# DialogFragment instances - assign different actions

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am having lots of issues understanding how DialoFragment works.

I need to generate 6 similar structured AlertDialog in my Fragment when clicking 6 different action buttons. Only thing is, the Dialog's PositiveButton onClick event will be different on each case (based on which action button was clicked).

Instead of writing same lines of codes 6 times, I was trying to use DIalogFragment. So far, i have come to the point that I can successfully display 6 different alerts, but still can't make a way of assigning different tasks to them. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class AlertDialogSingleField extends DialogFragment{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        String title = args.getString("title");
        AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_field_alert, null);
        myDialog.setView(layout);
        myDialog.setTitle(title);

        myDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //ACTIONS HERE WILL BE DIFFERENT DEPENDING ON WHICH METHOD WAS CALLED TO CREATE THIS DIALOG
            }
        });
        return myDialog.create();
    }

    public Interface testActions{
        public void ActionForalert1();
        public void ActionForalert2();
    }
}

public class ImportExportFragment extends Fragment implements testActions{
    public void alert1(){
        DialogFragment alertdialog = new AlertDialogSingleField();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", "Title1");
        alertdialog.setArguments(args);
        alertdialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "alert1");
    }

    public void alert2(){
        DialogFragment alertdialog = new AlertDialogSingleField();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", "Title2");
        alertdialog.setArguments(args);
        alertdialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "alert2");
    }

    public void ActionForalert1(){
        //THINGS TO DO WHEN AlertDialog created through alert1 method
    }

    public void ActionForalert2(){
        //THINGS TO DO WHEN AlertDialog created through alert2 method
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a way. Just posting for reference. Change in 2 functions in original code (in question) should do the trick.

**In main fragment:**

```
public void alert1(){
        DialogFragment alertdialog = new AlertDialogSingleField();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", "Title1");
        alertdialog.setArguments(args);
        alertdialog.setTargetFragment(this,0); **//ADD THIS LINE**
        alertdialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "alert1");
}
```

**In DIalog Fragment:**

```
myDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Fragment ft = getTargetFragment();
                if(ft != null){
                    ((eximaction) ft).importFromInternalMemory(et.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use dialog positive button listener as instance variable

```
public class AlertDialogSingleField extends DialogFragment{

    DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveListener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        String title = args.getString("title");
        AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_field_alert, null);
        myDialog.setView(layout);
        myDialog.setTitle(title);
        myDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", positiveListener);
        return myDialog.create();
    }

    public void setPositiveListener(DialogInterface.OnClickListener positiveListener){
        this.positiveListener = positiveListener;
    }

    public Interface testActions{
        public void ActionForalert1();
        public void ActionForalert2();
    }


}

public class ImportExportFragment extends Fragment implements testActions{

    public void alert1(){
        DialogFragment alertdialog = new AlertDialogSingleField();
        alertdialog.setPositiveListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                       ActionForalert1();
                    }
                });
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", "Title1");
        alertdialog.setArguments(args);
        alertdialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "alert1");
    }

    public void alert2(){
        DialogFragment alertdialog = new AlertDialogSingleField();
            alertdialog.setPositiveListener(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        ActionForalert2();
                    }
                });
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", "Title2");
        alertdialog.setArguments(args);
        alertdialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "alert2");
    }

    public void ActionForalert1(){
        //THINGS TO DO WHEN AlertDialog created through alert1 method
    }

    public void ActionForalert2(){
        //THINGS TO DO WHEN AlertDialog created through alert2 method
    }
}
```